# Is there a way to mark an argument as non-null after a function call?

Tags: typescript

Let’s assume we have a function to check that an argument is valid for our use (simplified example):

```
function isValid(value: string | undefined): boolean {
  return !!value && value.length > 2;
}
```

This function checks for `undefined` but if I use it to check the value before using it TypeScript still complains that the variable can be undefined, which is kind of understandable.

Is there a way to say “hey, if this function returns true then the argument can’t be `undefined`? I know I could give the code as a function to the check and have it call it if the value is valid but that’s not usable everywhere and looks ugly.

This would simplify code a lot when we don’t need to write

```
if (!!value && isValid(value)) functionRequiringString(value);
```

and instead use

```
if (isValid(value)) functionRequiringString(value);
```

when we have `value` that is typed as `string | undefined`.

Comment: `: value is string`? You're effectively writing a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: @jonrsharpe `value` is `string | undefined` coming in

Comment: Yes, and the return type can be "whether or not that was a string".

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry, misunderstood since the code font wasn’t clear. Yes, type predicate is exactly the term I was looking for. Thanks! Please provide it as an answer and I’ll accept